# How to always start gvim maximized in Linux?

Tags: linux, gvim

```
set lines=999 columns=999
```

doesn't work, and

```
au GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

only works for Windows.

Comment: What WM are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's your window manager who takes care about setting the initial window size. To get gvim maximized, you need to convince him to do that. This does of course depend on the window manager used.

Alternatively, define a window manager shortcut to maximize windows and use that after starting gvim.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Linux by setting 'lines' and 'columns' to large values, but for some reason they can't be arbitrarily large.  I found I had to set each of them to either the same values as a maximized window or slightly larger.  For example, setting lines=99 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run GVim using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec=/usr/bin/gvim #here you can modify the location of gvim
$exec -f $* &
pid=$!
winid=""
while [ -z $winid ]; do
  sleep 0.05
  winid=`wmctrl -pl |grep -P "^0x[0-9a-f]+[ ]+[-0-9]+[ ]+$pid" | cut -f1 -d' '`
done
# echo "debug: $exec started, PID=$pid, Window ID=$winid"

#this maximizes the GVim window
wmctrl -i -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz -r $winid

#this switches the GVim window to fullscreen
wmctrl -i -b add,fullscreen -r $winid
```

If you want to have this as the default whenever you call `gvim`, you can, e.g., save this script as `/usr/local/bin/gvim`.